# How to "reset" an array with messages with .subscribe?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

In my messages.component.ts im using

```
constructor(public messagesService: MessagesService) {
    this.subscription = this.messagesService.getMessage().subscribe(message => { this.messages.push(message); });
    this.subscription = this.messagesService.clearMessages().subscribe(this.messages = []);
  }
```

and clearMessages does this:

```
clearMessages(): void {
    this.subject.next();
  }
```

How do i combine this with .subscribe(), because subscribe() doesn't exist on type void?

Comment: This seems to be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). It's not clear what your trying to do but I'm pretty sure this is not the right approach

Comment: What does `getMessage()` return?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the lack of details, I am assuming `getMessage()` function looks something like

```js
getMessage(): Observable<any> {
  this.subject.asObservable();
}
```

In that case you could for instance emit `false` boolean in the `clearMessages()` function.

```js
clearMessages() {
  this.subject.next(false);
}
```

And since it doesn't return an observable, you can't subscribe to it. But the subscription isn't required since it's already subscribed to the `getMessage()` function. You could now check if the notification is valid before pushing it to the array.

```js
constructor(public messagesService: MessagesService) {
  this.subscription = this.messagesService.getMessage().subscribe(message => {
    if (!!message) this.messages.push(message); // <-- push only valid `message`
    else this.messages = []; // <-- assign empty array if `message` isn't defined
  });
}
```